# How to Copy Excel Query Tables to word, with text in between

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to set up a macro to copy the contents of my Excel Query Tables to word based  on whether they have retried data. And separate them with a line of text.

Currently my code successful does the first half but they join together ruining the layout. 
I am hoping to keep the tables inserts modular as i will need to add more tables later on.

Also for some reason my Notes table ends up on top, not a big issue but would prefer to keep the inserts in order.

```
Sub WordOutput3()
Dim objword
Dim objdoc
Dim Selection As Excel.Range
Dim WordTable


'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Create Word Doc with Thin Margins
    Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objdoc = objword.Documents.Add
objword.Visible = True
objdoc.PageSetup.TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
objdoc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
objdoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
objdoc.PageSetup.RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    objword.Activate
 'Transactions

 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Transactions")) >= 1 Then

Set Selection = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TF_Flags").ListObjects("Transactions").Range
   Selection.Copy

 'Paste Table into MS Word
  objdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False
   objdoc.Paragraphs.Add

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
objword.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (2)


'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

   End If

'notes
 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Notes")) >= 1 Then

Set Selection = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TF_Flags").ListObjects("Notes").Range
   Selection.Copy

 'Paste Table into MS Word
  objdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False


'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
objword.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (2)

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tables are all being pasted into the same place as the code you are using puts them into the first paragraph.

```
objdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
```

You need to change this so that you always add the table to the last paragraph of the document.

```
objdoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
```

After each table there needs to be an empty paragraph to prevent Word from merging your tables into one. In your code you do add a new paragraph after the addition of the first table, `objdoc.Paragraphs.Add`, but you don't do anything with it. As you are conditionally adding a second table it would be better to move that line of code so that the paragraph is added before pasting in the second table, i.e.

```
'Paste Table into MS Word
objdoc.Paragraphs.Add
objdoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteExcelTable _
  LinkedToExcel:=False, _
  WordFormatting:=False, _
  RTF:=False
```

Comment: This Worked AND explained it in a way a noob like me can understand :)

Any idea why the tables are adding in the wrong order or should i make that a separate question?

Comment: If you insert each table into the last paragraph of the document they will be in the order they were inserted, i.e. first, second, third, etc. The only possible reason I can think of for that not happening would be if the first paste hasn’t completed before the second is executed, in which case Word may not have updated its paragraph collection.